# What is the use of tunneling the CommandBinding.previewcanexecute event ??

Tags: wpf, commandbinding, routedcommand

What is the use of tunneling  the CommandBinding.previewcanexecute event ?

and bubbling the CommandBinding.canexecute event ?? How is it useful

Answer (score 0):

Tunnelling and bubbling events allow handlers to be shared among several elements, and intercepted by controls higher in the hierarchy.  For example, given the following Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
   <Button Command="MyCommand" />
   <Button Command="MyCommand" />
   <Button Command="MyCommand" />
   <Button Command="MyCommand" />
</StackPanel>
```

If I want to define a single `CommandBinding` for `MyCommand` that will affect all of the buttons, I can define it on the `StackPanel`.  When each button tries to execute its command, the event will bubble upwards to the `StackPanel` - meaning that we need only one handler for four buttons.  If I placed a handler at the root `Window` level, it would apply to *every* button in my application.

Conversely, tunnelling an event allows you to intercept it before it gets to the control that fired it.  So, for example, if I want to *disable* a command for every button across my entire `Window`, I could do this with a tunnelling event and the buttons would always find that `CanExecute` returns `false`.